# What these options exactly mean in ifup command in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell

Please can someone explain to me more (maybe with examples ) about the following options in `ifup` command in Linux.

This is what I found on the internet, but with no more details about it :

> - `--force` Force configuration or deconfiguration of the interface.
> - `--allow=CLASS` Only allow interfaces listed in an allow-`CLASS` line in `/etc/network/interfaces` to be acted upon.
> - `-X PATTERN`, `--exclude=PATTERN` Exclude interfaces from the list of interfaces to operate on by the `PATTERN`. `PATTERN` uses a usual shell glob syntax. If shell wildcards are not used, it must match the exact interface name. This option may be specified multiple times resulting in more than one pattern being excluded.
> - `-o OPTION=VALUE` Set `OPTION` to `VALUE` as though it were in `/etc/network/interfaces`.
> - `-n`, `--no-act` Don't configure any interfaces or run any "`up`" or "`down`" commands.
> - `--no-mappings` Don't run any mappings. See `interfaces` for more information about the mapping feature.
> - `--no-scripts` Don't run any scripts under `/etc/network/if-*.d/`
> - `-l`, `--list` For `ifquery`, list all the interfaces which match the specified class. If no class specified, prints all the interfaces listed as `auto`.

I'm using Centos 6 and couldn't find the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, maybe because I'm using Network Manger and not static IP settings.

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is a debian file.  On CentOS the analogous file(s) are `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<dev>`

Comment: Thanks for the replay , i guess these options are not available in centor because the ifup command only takes the interface name

Comment: sorry i mean centos

Comment: Those options don't exist in the CentOs version of ifup.  Try running `man ifup` to see if it lists any such options, if not, then you don't have a version with those flags/options.  You'll need to move to, say, an Ubuntu system and then you can experiment with those options